# Reading mouse/keyboard events on Virtual Machine(VM) Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, events, virtual-machine, vmware, evdev

Basically I need to read mouse & keyboard events, so the program will know when you are pressing keys or scrolling.

It works fine on my physical machine, but does not show any events when I connect to virtual machine(VMware in my case) via Remmina VNC(from Ubuntu). Despite, both mouse and keyboard work as usual in VM.
I have tried connecting to all available devices in `/dev/input` but still it's quiet. Then I tested all devices with [evtest](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection/evtest) and got the same result - nothing.

I don't think, that it depends on my code, but I used this [library](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/libevdev/doc/latest/).

Does it possible to achieve this? Maybe I missed something important? Any help, articles or links would be greatly appreciated.

---

UPDATE: I've recently tried a `xinput`:

```
xinput list
```

There were another devices, called `Virtual core XTEST pointer` and `Virtual core XTEST keyboard` that actually showed events with help of `xinput test <ID>`. These devices are not listed in `/proc/bus/input/devices`, so I have hope that will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have implemented a listener for xinput with commands `xinput test Virtual core XTEST pointer` and `xinput test Virtual core XTEST keyboard`. As I have read from [this article](https://www.linux.org/threads/cool-tricks-with-xinput-device.10345/), each master device have a `Virtual core XTEST...`.

I am using QT, and code is looks like this:

```
...
mouseProcess = new QProcess(this);
mouseProcess->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);

// Listen to output of process with function ReadOut()
connect(mouseProcess, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), SLOT(ReadOut()));
mouseProcess->start("xinput", QStringList() << "test" << "Virtual core XTEST pointer");
...


void ReadOutMouse() {
    QByteArray out = mouseProcess->readAllStandardOutput();
    QString output(out);
    if (output.contains("button press"))
        emit mouseEvent();
}

...

// The same is for Keyboard:
void ReadOutKeyboard() {
    QByteArray out = keyboardProcess->readAllStandardOutput();
    QString output(out);
    if (output.contains("key release"))
        emit keyboardEvent();
}
```